# Object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to do a command !clear that will delete messages in chat, but here is a problem. It shows that my context has no attribute 'channel'

```
class bCommands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_ready(self):
            print("Bot is ready")

    @commands.command()
        async def hi(self, ctx):
            await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.message.author.name}")

    @commands.command()
        async def clear(ctx, amount=1):
            await ctx.channel.message.purge(limit=amount)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(bCommands(bot))


**Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'bCommands' object has no attribute 'channel'**
```

Answer (score 1):

`async def clear(ctx, amount=1):` is missing `self` as the first parameter. Self is still being passed in as an argument, and it's ending up as `ctx` and you're doing `ctx.channel` which is a bCommands instance instead of whatever it's supposed to be. It should likely be

```
async def clear(self, ctx, amount=1):
```